# is it possible to make the caret jump between highlighted text snippets in Scintilla?

Tags: scintilla

I want to know if it is possible with Scintilla API to make something like the following.

I have the following call:

cook(foo  , bar);

where foo and bar are only highlighted and the caret is at the beginning of foo.

now if i type anything, it will override foo, and if I pressed Tab, the caret will jump to the highlighted bar.

Answer (score 0):

[FingerText](https://github.com/erinata/FingerText) does this with snippets (for Notepad++), but the majority of it uses Scintilla, so I would imagine it should be possible to fairly easily adapt it for another Scintilla based editor.